# R: reshaping dataframe into matrix of 1's and 0's

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert dataframe of this type format:

```
  V1 V2
  1  a
  2  a
  3  b
  4  c
  5  c
```

into a matrix of this format:

```
  V1 a  b  c
  1  1  0  0
  2  1  0  0
  3  0  1  0
  4  0  0  1
  5  0  0  1
```

What is the best way to do this in R? I've tried to use reshape2, but couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

`table` should be sufficient for this:

```
with(mydf, cbind(V1, table(1:nrow(mydf), V2)))
##   V1 a b c
## 1  1 1 0 0
## 2  2 1 0 0
## 3  3 0 1 0
## 4  4 0 0 1
## 5  5 0 0 1
```

Alternatively, you can look at `model.matrix`:

```
cbind(mydf["V1"], model.matrix(~V2 + 0, mydf))
##   V1 V2a V2b V2c
## 1  1   1   0   0
## 2  2   1   0   0
## 3  3   0   1   0
## 4  4   0   0   1
## 5  5   0   0   1
```

Comment: Alternatively, you really just need `cbind(mydf$V1, table(mydf))`

Comment: I don't really want to make any assumptions about what is in the first column. Again, I prefer generalizable answers to ones which address a narrow single-user's needs.

Comment: oh well then I guess you'll need to stop using with since not every user will have V1 as a variable. you should use column indexing which is more generalizable

Comment: Alternatively, maybe a function which searches through the columns for variables which are character strings and compare that to other columns which may or may not exist and make a best guess at which column the user really wanted to use without any regard for the data structure. that would be the best solution

Comment: Yeah, as long as `V1` does not contain repeating values, @rawr 's suggestion of `table(mydf)` would do it. But that *is* an assumption.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe is a shortcut but that's not the same of this?

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(dat, V1 ~ V2, length )
Using V2 as value column: use value.var to override.
  V1 a b c
1  1 1 0 0
2  2 1 0 0
3  3 0 1 0
4  4 0 0 1
5  5 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the special functions for this, but I might do...

```
uv <- unique(DF$V2)
m  <- matrix(0L,nrow(DF),length(uv),dimnames=list(DF$V1,uv))
m[ cbind(1:nrow(m), match(DF$V2,uv)) ] <- 1L
```

This is a matrix of zeros and ones, unlike the other answers so far. (Of course, small difference.)

```
  a b c
1 1 0 0
2 1 0 0
3 0 1 0
4 0 0 1
5 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative

```
library(tidyr)
out = cbind(dat[1], 
      apply(spread(dat, V2, V2)[-1], 2, 
            function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, 1)))

#  V1 a b c
#1  1 1 0 0
#2  2 1 0 0
#3  3 0 1 0
#4  4 0 0 1
#5  5 0 0 1
```

more simplified as @SamFirke suggested

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% mutate(x = 1) %>% spread(V2, x, fill = 0)

#  V1 a b c
#1  1 1 0 0
#2  2 1 0 0
#3  3 0 1 0
#4  4 0 0 1
#5  5 0 0 1
```

Comment: Or using the `fill` argument of `spread`: `dat %>% mutate(x = 1) %>% spread(V2, x, fill = 0)` (also requires the dplyr package)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code-golf answer:

```
model.matrix(~.-1,df)
##   V1 V2a V2b V2c
## 1  1   1   0   0
## 2  2   1   0   0
## 3  3   0   1   0
## 4  4   0   0   1
## 5  5   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `mtabulate` from **qdapTools**:

```
library(qdapTools)
data.frame(dat[, 1, drop=F], mtabulate(setNames(dat[[2]], dat[[1]])))

##   V1 a b c
## 1  1 1 0 0
## 2  2 1 0 0
## 3  3 0 1 0
## 4  4 0 0 1
## 5  5 0 0 1
```